# Difference between asInstanceOf[ ] and isInstanceOf[ ] in scala

Tags: scala

What is the difference between `asInstanceOf[]` and `isInstanceOf[]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, `a.asInstanceOf[B]` performs the actual cast: it takes an object of type A and returns (if possible) object of type B, whereas `a.isInstanceOf[B]` returns boolean indicating whether `a` has type `B` or not.

Strictly speaking isInstanceOf[B] looks not only if a is of type B, but if a has type B in the upper side inheritance tree (so if B superclass of a, isInstanceOf yield true) and important notice is that isInstanceOf works on the actual object type hierarchy rather on the reference type.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just like to add that the common pattern

```
if (x.isInstanceOf[B]) {
    val b = x.asInstanceOf[B];
    ...
} else ...
```

can be written nicely as

```
x match {
    case (b: B) => ...
    ...
}
```

This is especially useful if there are multiple tests of this kind for a single `x`.